# parsed values are getting truncated on unix platform while parsing xml using dom4j and jdk 7

Tags: java, xml, unix, dom4j

I am using dom4j to parse xml. Parsing is going smooth on windows platform(jdk 7) and when I deploy same code on UNIX having jdk 7 over there, its truncating the parsed values on random basis. Sometimes it don't parse few values at all.

Issue is not producible on window and as its random on UNIX, I am not able to trace the root cause. Code is running in batch mode at both places. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Without more information, not really. I suggest you work on reproducing this in a minimal way. We have no idea where the XML is coming from, what's triggering the parsing etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you get random corruptions in the data from the XML parser that's shipped with the JDK, the first thing to do is to try it with Apache Xerces instead. This often solves the problem. The JDK parser, although it's based on some version of Apache Xerces, has some nasty bugs. I think they finally got fixed in JDK 8, but I wouldn't swear to it.

(You'll have to look up the details of how to configure DOM4J to use a different SAX parser underneath).

Comment: thanks for your guidance. does dom4j works on windows and breaks on UNIX? When I do revers testing on my local windows machine, everything gets parsed fine.

Comment: Firstly I'm only guessing that this is the JDK parser bug (and therefore nothing to do with DOM4J). Secondly, I have no idea whether this bug is platform-dependent, but it wouldn't surprise me. There's no point asking me further questions, until you have followed up my suggestion of trying it with Apache Xerces to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hello Michael, one doubt. does Xerxes support xpath?

Comment: Xerces is an XML parser, not an XPath engine. It feeds data into DOM4J, and DOM4J gives you access to XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Using JDOM library solved my issue.